# Does running a job remotely slow it down?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos, speed

I am running some computationally expensive jobs, and would like to run them in the fastest way possible. I have three options:

1. ssh from workstation A in network A (Ubuntu) into workstations B, C, D etc in network B (Centos) to run the jobs
2. physically walk to workstation B in network B and ssh into workstations C, D etc to run the jobs
3. physically walk to each workstation to run the jobs

Would they all run at the same speed? If not, which would be the fastest, and why?

Comment: In all three options the performance of the workstations should be the same. One thing to note is, if you use ssh and you put a high load on the workstation, your session could be slow.

Comment: There would be a difference if you have to transfer large amounts of data and the network is slow, in which case a USB disk and a pair of sneakers could have a lot more bandwidth.

Comment: *"I am running some computationally expensive jobs"* -- You probably mean computationally *intensive*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using version 1., but with a twist: Use a session managemnet tool like `screen`, `tmux` and friends.

This solves two problems:

- If the **console output** from a job is faster than your network speed, the job will indeed slow down (rather not likely in a LAN, but may easily be over the internet). By detaching from your `screen` session this problem goes away.
- If you drop your SSH connection (e.g. by fat-fingering), the remote job will catch a SIGHUP and will end. If you use `screen`, it will keep running and you can later reattach.

Comment: I guess [in some cases](https://superuser.com/q/1178434/432690) version 1 *may* be faster even without `screen`/`tmux`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The `screen` argument stands even for a local console - who hasn't fat fingered a `Ctrl-C` to the wrong console?

Comment: Yes, I know. Your talking to a guy who uses `tmux` a lot – even on his parents' home router. :)

Comment: Wait. Does `screen` act as a screen to protect you from accidental Ctrl+C?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It does - if you use it to move the hairy jobs out of danger while you wrestle your terminals and consoles. I tend to have a `top` running on the active window of screen when I am not activly using that terminal.

Comment: Oh, this way. OK, I totally get it now.