# 'ls' command very slow

Tags: terminal, ls

I have about 17k files in a directory. When I run `ls directory`, I have to wait for about 15-20 seconds before the results are displayed. On the other hand, when I run `ls directory | wc -l` or `ls directory | grep .xyz`, the results are displayed immediately.

Why does this happen and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It happens because there are 17k files in the directory. The solution is to have fewer files in the directory.

Comment: printing to console is always slow. OTOH passing the data through a pipe will leave the output in memory or file so it'll be a lot faster

Comment: This issue is related to the display (?) buffer of the console. The "slowness" comes from outputting the data through the buffer, not the command itself.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what if you are an ML engineer?

Comment: I'd find a better way to organize the data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're using Linux.

1. If your `ls` command is aliased such that it shows files and folders in colour, then it needs to find out each item's permissions (a stat() call) and whether it has any "file capabilities" set (a getxattr() call) in order to choose the right colour. Depending on file system, these calls can be fairly slow if the required metadata hasn't been cached in RAM yet. [Extended attributes often live in the data area, so each getxattr results in HDD seeks.]

   On the other hand, `ls |` when redirected to a pipe automatically disables colouring, so it no longer needs to do any extra checks – just a straightforward readdir() loop which returns the file name and type, and the kernel likely even implements read-ahead for that.
2. <del>nonsense</del>

Use `strace` or `perf trace` to check which system calls, if any, are taking a long time.

Comment: But `ls directory | wc -l` won’t produce any output until after the `ls` completes.   And, even when writing to something other than a terminal, `ls` *sorts* the directory by default, so it still can’t output anything before it has read the entire directory.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` sorts output by default. Try `ls -f` to disable sorting and colorizing output.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If you run `ls` first and `ls | wc -l` later, its possible the former will read from your HDD and the latter will read cached data. If so, `ls` initially "stalls" and prints nothing for few seconds. Another `ls` will start printing almost immediately, as long as the cached data is still there. If you started with `ls | wc -l` in the first place, *it* would have to wait for HDD to supply data.
2. Any terminal works with its own speed. Formally `stty speed` will show you some value, but I think it doesn't matter for a virtual terminal. Still, displaying characters and scrolling takes time (see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1166976/432690)). Passing the same data through a pipe is faster.

Comment: You suggest that *writing to the display* is a significant factor in the timing.  This can be tested with some experiments: Run the following commands: ``ls -C directory > tmp`` (adding ``--color=always`` if `ls` is normally aliased to use `--color`), ``cat tmp``, and ``ls directory | cat``, and look at how long they take.

Comment: @Scott I suggest it can be, especially if one uses like `/dev/tty2`. I have a directory with 200k files and I don't even need to test thoroughly. In `/dev/tty2` the command scrolls and scrolls and scrolls… And in `konsole` it prints in no time. Straightforward `time ls` yielded 30s and 1.4s respectively; for `ls | wc -l` this was 0,5s in both terminals. All tests were done after initial `ls` that actually obtained data from my not-so-fast HDD and allowed the OS to cache it. The results are repeatable.